# Getting value from controller to view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get data passed from controller to view. I believe I am really close, but I am missing some tiny piece.

Controller:

```
namespace ePolicy.ConsumerPortal.Controllers
{
    [HandleErrors]
    public class TwoFAController : BaseController
    {
        [AcceptVerbs(new string[1] { "GET" })]
        public ActionResult SMS(string supplierId)
        {
            var model = new _2FASMSModel();
            return View("TwoFA_sms", model);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(new string[1] { "POST" }), ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Initiate(FormCollection formValues, string email, string phone, string method)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("SMS", "TwoFA", new { phone = "1234567890"})
        }
    }
}
```

The model class:

```
public class _2FASMSModel : BaseModel
{
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public _2FASMSModel()
    {
    }
}
```

The view (`.aspx` file)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/ConsumerPortalNew.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ePolicy.ConsumerPortal.Models._2FASMSModel>" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="ePolicy.Resources" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="ePolicy.Shared.Enumeration" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="login" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.StaticFile("/Scripts/TwoFA.js")%>"></script>
    <div>
       <p>@Model.Phone</p>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**What I wanted to do:** I want to display the string "1234567890" in my view file.

**What I have tried**: I was able to make "1234567890" part of URL parameter, however, I was not able to retrieve this string so I can display in my view.

`@Model.Phone` will be interpreted as literal string instead of the value ("1234567890") that I wanted it to be.

I also tried to use the `ViewBag` by adding this line

```
ViewBag.Phone = supplierID
```

before returning a view. and calling it in view:

```
<p>ViewBag.Phone</p>
```

It did not work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using ASPX, when the popular (and IMO far superior) view engine for MVC is Razor?

Comment: @mason i don't have a say for this. This is a existing project that I(as intern) suppose to work on.

Comment: Ouch. Well my condolences to you. I hope you don't go forward thinking that ASPX (the Web Forms View Engine) is representative of the quality of the framework as a whole. It gets better.

Comment: @mason this is actually good to hear. I really don't like ASPX. Glad to hear there are better choices.

Comment: change public ActionResult SMS(string supplierId) to public ActionResult SMS(string phone) and do var model = new _2FASMSModel() {Phone = phone} before returning

Comment: @KarthikGanesan thanks, that worked  too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to change:

```
<p>@Model.Phone</p>
```

to:

```
<p><%: Model.Phone %></p>
```

And don't forget to actually fill your model with data:

```
[AcceptVerbs(new string[1] { "GET" })]
public ActionResult SMS(string supplierId)
{
    var model = new _2FASMSModel() { Phone = "HTC 10" };
    return View("TwoFA_sms", model);
}
```

That should at least display some dynamic data on your view. The last step is to pass on data from one controller action to the other. In ASP.NET MVC, there's a `TempData` property on your controller you can use. It's a dictionary where you can literally store a bit of data that will be available on the next request. It seems that's exactly what you want.

```
[AcceptVerbs(new string[1] { "GET" })]
public ActionResult SMS(string supplierId)
{
    var model = new _2FASMSModel() { Phone = TempData["Phone"] as string };
    return View("TwoFA_sms", model);
}

[AcceptVerbs(new string[1] { "POST" }), ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Initiate(FormCollection formValues, string email, string phone, string method)
{
    TempData["Phone"] = "1234567890";
    return RedirectToAction("SMS", "TwoFA");
}
```

Comment: For the last line,`return RedirectToAction("SMS", "TwoFA", )`, is there another paremeter? since it seems like it.

Comment: Nope. Forget to remove that. Updated my answer :-). I also now only store a string in tempdata instead of an anonymous object, the object was not needed.

Comment: The error occured at line: `var model = new _2FASMSModel() { Phone = TempData["Phone"] };` Apparently it treats `TempData["Phone"]` as object and it sais that cannot implicitly convert type object to string

Answer (score 0):

```
[AcceptVerbs(new string[1] { "GET" })]
```

public ActionResult SMS(string supplierId){
var model = new _2FASMSModel();

model.Phone = "1234567890";

return View("TwoFA_sms", model);
}

View

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })